# Updating dialogfragment views from outside the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

Is it possible to update any of the views of a dialogfragment, like a textview from the parent activity or fragment? I have a progressdialog that should be dismissed once some text has been loaded from a service and displayed in the textview.

The data is indeed received but the progressdialog is never dismissed nor the texview displayed.

Here is my dialogfragment code:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class ArtistInfoDialog extends DialogFragment {

    ImageButton close;
    TextView title;
    TextView artist;
    ImageView art;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.artist_info_layout, container, false);

        artistInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist_info);
        close = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.close);
        loadingIndicator = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) view.findViewById(R.id.loadingIndicator);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        artist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        art = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.art);

        Track track = NakedGroove.getCurrentPlaylist().get(NakedGroove.getCurrentIndex());

        title.setText(track.getTitle());
        artist.setText(track.getArtist());

        if (!track.getImages().isEmpty())
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(track.getMediumImage()).fit().centerCrop().error(R.drawable.no_cover).placeholder(R.drawable.no_cover).into(art);
        else
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.no_cover).fit().centerCrop().into(art);

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return view;
    }
}
```

The EventBus code is as follows:

```
  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(ArtistMetadataEvent metadataEvent) {
    String info = metadataEvent.bio;

    if (artistInfoDialog != null) {
        loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        artistInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(info)) {
            artistInfo.setText(info);
        } else {
            artistInfo.setText("Artist information unavailable");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do this either with an interface or some implementation of an event bus.

Comment: I am using an eventbus to receive the result from the service and set the text. Let me give the interface approach a try.

Comment: With no code, that's almost i can offer to help. Eventbus is probably a better approach as it is more 'decoupled' than an interface. I don't see any reason why it shouldnt work. Perhaps you're missing a small detail?

Comment: When and how do you subscribe your dialogfragment to the eventbus? If this subscription happens after the text is loaded from a service your `onEvent` method will never be called since the event isnt sticky. You should probably debug to see if the dialog actually receives the event or not. This will also give you a better idea on why the expected behaviour isnt happening if it is indeed receiving the event

Comment: I subscribed the dialogfragment to the eventbus on the onstart method but it is not updating the content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114747/discussion-between-howdoidothis-and-alex-kombo).

Comment: @AlexKombo did you find any solution